# Regular expression for extracting a noun in variable order

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, backreference, named-captures

I have the following text:

```
Action by Toni Kroos, Real Madrid. Rayo Vallecano 2, Real Madrid 0.
```

where the nouns are `Toni Kroos`, `Real Madrid` (`team1`) and `Rayo Vallecano` (`team2`).

I need a regular expression with a named capturing group that returns these results given the following variations:

```
Action by Toni Kroos, Real Madrid. Rayo Vallecano 2, Real Madrid 0.
```

Expected result: `Rayo Vallecano`

```
Action by Toni Kroos, Real Madrid. Real Madrid 0, Rayo Vallecano 2.
```

Expected result: `Rayo Vallecano`

My naive intention was to negate the backreference captured in `team1` and use it on the second sentence. So when it is about to match `Real Madrid` or `Rayo Vallecano`, it would discard `Real Madrid` as is the same value as `team1`. So `team2` would return `Rayo Vallecano`. No lucky so far with something like (it only works on the first example):

```
^Action by .*\, (?<team1>.*)\. (?!\1)(?<team2>.*)( \d+\,| \d+\.).
```

In plain English, my expectation is a regex to pick either the first noun or the second one on the second sentence (after the first `.`) so `team2` would be either `Real Madrid` or `Rayo Vallecano` in the examples, and then discard the one that matches the named capturing group `team1` (`Real Madrid` in the example). So it wouldn't matter the order of the noun in the second sentence.

I'm no expert with regular expressions, so I'm not sure that's possible to achieve with one unique pattern that fits both examples. Is it possible to get such expression? If so, I would appreciate the solution with an explanation of the pattern used. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The language I'll be using is JavaScript

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: If you use a named capture group, you need to use a named back-reference.

Comment: Hi @Barmar. Thanks for your answer. I'm using JavaScript. Can you please explain how to use it in this example? I've (wrongly) tried with `(?!\1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write the pattern using `\1` to refer to the first capture group and use the named group `team1` and `team2` only once.

```
^Action by [^,]*, (?<team1>[^.]+)[.,] (?:\1[^,]*, )?(?<team2>[^,]+) \d+[,.]
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Action by [^,]*,`  Match `Action by`  followed by optional chars other than a comma and then match `,`
- `(?<team1>[^.]+)[.,]`  Group **team1** match 1+ chars other than `.` then then match either `.` or `,`
- `(?:\1[^,]*, )?` Optionally match what is matched by group 1 using a backreference followed by optional chars other than `,` followed by matching `,`
- `(?<team2>[^,]+)`  Named group **team2** match 1+ chars other than `,` and then match a space
- `\d+[,.]` Match 1+ digits followed by `,` or `.`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kCrd1X/1).

```js
const regex = /^Action by [^,]*, (?<team1>[^.]+)[.,] (?:\1[^,]*, )?(?<team2>[^,]+) \d+[,.]/;
[
  `Action by Toni Kroos, Real Madrid. Rayo Vallecano 2, Real Madrid 0.`,
  `Action by Toni Kroos, Real Madrid. Real Madrid 0, Rayo Vallecano 2.`
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m.groups);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. That exactly what I meant with my poor explanation. However, your proposal yields `Madrid` in the first example, and `Vallecano` in the second one. It should return the value `Rayo Vallecano` in both examples

Comment: @DavidMiguelYusta Yes I see, let me update it...

Comment: Mister, you nailed it. Many many thanks. Could I ask for one last thing? If you could add a brief explanation for future readers (and myself) with the same problem, it would be awesome.

Comment: @DavidMiguelYusta I have slightly updated the pattern and added an explanation to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression with named capturing groups:

```
Action by.*, (?<team1>.*)\. (?<team2>.*) (\d+), (?<team1>.*) (\d+)\.
```

This regex matches the text and captures the values of `team1` and `team2` using named capturing groups. Note that the named capturing group `team1` is used twice in the expression to capture both values of the same team.

Comment: Hi @oria kali. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I get an error when using the same named capturing group (`team1`) more than once (according to regex101.com). Also, wouldn't your proposal only work with the first example and not on the second?

Comment: The formatting errors in the original answer obscured what was being proposed. I tried to fix them, but since your question was rather unclear, probably don't get your hopes too high.

Comment: Hi @tripleee. Many thanks. `team2` should be the value of the noun that doesn't match `team1`. In the second sentence after the first `.` will always have 2 team: one that matches `team1` and the other (the expected result). The problem is that in the second sentence, the order may vary. In the first example `Rayo Vallecano` is first, and on the other example is second. Does it make it more clear?

Comment: Probably edit your question rather than hide details in a comment to an answer. You want to make sure you include all your requirements, and enough test examples to illustrate the corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: (https://regex101.com/r/yYgl5R/1)

Regex: `^Action by .*\, (.*)\. (?<team1>.*)( \d+\,) (?<team2>.*)(\d+\.)`

This matches only the teams, and the score